# what and where can I find the database/table files for sql server 2005?

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2005, portability

In my sql server 2005 I have a database named *movies* . In this database I have a table named *list*. I wanted to test my application on some another machine. Is there any way I can take with me that database or tables so that there is no need to create them again there. What type of files are they if there is a way  out other than creating a new database and tables again

Comment: This [How To tutorial](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;Q304692) should sum it up for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing you can do is to take a local backup of the database (if you you want all the transactions as well include the transaction log file).  Then put that .BAK file on a thumb drive and go to the other machine.  Once at the other machine you can "Restore" the .BAK as the database on this new machine.

Here is a screen shot of the "Back Up..." and restore options:

[image]

You'll want to 1st back it up to either a network location or even onto say the desktop of the first machine.  You can keep most of the defaults when you do a backup and I would recommend a "FULL BACKUP".  Once you click ok, it will generate a Database.BAK file.  Then you can take this file to be used when you do a "Restore" on the other machine.  The restore can have the same database name or a different one on this 2nd machine.

Comment: @Jeremy - I need some photoshop skills :).